# Python equivalent to Scala groupby

Tags: python, scala

I have a list of objects, and I'd like a function that can take that list along with a function operating on the items in that list, and produce a dict with keys from the result of applying that function to the item, and values being a list of items with that key.

Example:

```
def group_by(iterable: Iterable[A], f: Callable[A, B]) -> Dict[B, List[A]]:
    ???

lst = [(1,2), (3,4), (1,3)]
result = group_by(lst, lambda i: i[0])
result == {1: [(1,2), (1,3)],
           3: [(3,4)]}
```

`itertools.groupby` is close, but I don't want to require that my input be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def group_by(iterable, f):
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for x in iterable:
        results[f(x)].append(x)
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
groups = []
uniquekeys = []
data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    # watch out! g is an iterator here, you must iterate it
    groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
    uniquekeys.append(k)

def my_groupby(fn,datum):
    d = {}
    for data in datum:
        d.setdefault(fn(d),[]).append(data)
    return d
```

Comment: `itertools.groupby` requires my input to be sorted - the scala function doesn't, and I don't want to make that a requirement of this data.

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly that `itertools.groupby` only groups consecutive elements with the same key, so you *must* sort the list first.

Comment: @Daenyth: Then you can sort it yourself inside your grouping function.

Comment: @BrenBarn: It shouldn't need to be sorted at all.

Comment: see my edit there you go ... my_groupby ... its not builtin but meh ... 4 lines of code ..

Comment: Also group by doesn't give you a dict, it gives you an annoying iterable of iterables